# Remove header declaration from flow type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I wonder why do we need a header declaration at the top of the files when we want to use flow.

I mean adding `/* @flow */` to all the files is a bit annoying.

Is there any way to tell which files/directories flow should look at?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flow check --all` to avoid having to adding this line to every file.

You can also specify included and ignored directories in the `.flowconfig` file. However, the --all option does not seem to be available in the `.flowconfig` file